# R: OutOfMemoryError (Java): GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: r, excel, matrix, lookup, xls

I've a script to lookup value from a matrix and fill cells in different worksheets within the same xls workbook. I'm facing an error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): GC overhead limit exceeded in between the run-time of the code. The below mentioned is the code, any support to rectify the issue will be much appreciated.Thank you.

```
require(XLConnect)
wb = loadWorkbook("F:/Projects/QC_QA_TEMP/template.xlsx")
memory.size()
rawdata = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Complete Users Report", header = TRUE)
str(rawdata)
city<-unique(rawdata$Location)

df = readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Category 15 a", header = TRUE)

df$City
question<-colnames(df)
question<-question[-c(1,2)]
result<-matrix(nrow = length(city), ncol =length(question))

str(result)
for (i in 1:length(city)){
  for (j in 1:length(question)){
    a <- subset(rawdata,Location==city[i] & Question==question[j])
    result[i,j]<-a$Response[1]

  }
} 
str(result)
summary(result)
writeWorksheet(wb,result,"Category 15 a",startRow = 3, startCol = 3, header = FALSE)
```

Comment: When was the error thrown? Can you reproduce it? What is the output from `traceback()` immediately after the error was thrown.